# Programmatically add retina and non-retina images to local store via writeToFile?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, save, nsfilemanager

Hello: I have a photo uploader in my application that will let players upload their own photos for use in my application. I crop and resize each uploaded image in order to create two images: an X-by-X pixel image (for non-retina displays) and a 2X-by-2X pixel image (for retina displays).

I then save both images to local player's Private Documents directory via `[photoDataNonRetina writeToFile:pathNonRetina atomically:YES]` and `[photoDataRetina writeToFile:pathRetina atomically:YES]` where photoDataNonRetina and photoDataRetina are NSData objects and the filenames for each image are `photo.png` and `photo@2x.png` respectively.

How should I subsequently retrieve my images from the local Private Documents directory so that the appropriate image is retrieved based on whether the device has a retina display? Right now I would guess doing something akin to the following:

```
NSString *path = [[self pathForPlayer:player] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.png"];
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

except that would seem only to load the non-retina image?

Comment: Why are you creating both sizes of images? A given device only needs one of the two sizes. Just create the size (X or 2X) required by the current device.

Comment: Unless you are using iCloud backups for your images and using on multiple devices with multiple scaled images (retina, iPad, etc) then I second the motion to only create the scaled images for your current device and save the storage space required for multiple images.

Comment: Eventually yes, I hope to be able to share photos across devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)]            &&
([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
  // Retina display
} else {
  // non-Retina display
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of checking if the main screen responds to the `displayLinkWithTarget:selector:` method? How is that related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1) {
  NSString *path = [[self pathForPlayer:player] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo@2x.png"];
  UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
  UIImage * retinaImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2 orientation:[image imageOrientation]];
  return retinaImage;
} else {
  NSString *path = [[self pathForPlayer:player] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.png"];
  return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the extension from the filename.

```
NSString *path = [[self pathForPlayer:player] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo"];
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: This seems promising! I'll have to try it. Will update once I do.